# How to make a python script run persistently?

Tags: script, process, remote-control

I have a remote server that I want to use to record livestreams. I ssh into the server and run a python script using nohup to monitor and record streams. problem is if I quit the ssh session, the script also quits. how do I keep the script running?

Answer (score 0):

For example if your python script is `myscript.py`, you need to put `&` at the end of the command as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2975645) from StackOverflow it to continue running even after you quit your ssh session. The command will be:

```
nohup python myscript.py &
```